# File upload with jwt token angular

Tags: angular, laravel

I am trying to upoload a file to my laravel backend using form data and I need to send the jwt bearer token. What headers should I use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should send Authorization header with your request . please try like this.

```
const headers = new Headers({
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
})

return this.http.post(apiUrl,formData , { headers: headers })
```

Comment: Do I need to specify the content-type in the header?

Comment: Might be needed.try without first. If not worked pass Content-Type : multipart/form-data

Comment: I added the header content-type and it worked. Thanks buddy.

Comment: That's great to hear buddy